# is there a way to specify the controller for {{render}}?

Tags: ember.js

The reason I want to do this is that I have a list of objects that should be displayed twice, once in expanded form and once in compact form. So I would like to do this:

```
{{render 'widgets' store.widgets}}
...

{{render 'widgets-compact' store.widgets}}
```

and in both cases use the WidgetsController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I realized after looking at the code that although it is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, you can just do controller=

```
{{render 'widgets-compact' store.widgets controller=widgets}}
```